# PHP: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause

Tags: php, odbc, driver

```
    //$query = "INSERT INTO Users (FullName, LocationsID) VALUES ('".$FullName."','".$Location."');";     
    $query = "INSERT INTO 'Users' (FullName, Password, LocationsID, Position, Mobile, Note, EngineerID, FirstName, LastName, Username) VALUES ('".$FullName."','".$Password."','".$Location."','".$Position."','".$Mobile."','".$Note."','".$Engineer."','".$FirstName."','".$LastName."','".$Username."','".$Email."');"; 

    $result=odbc_exec($insert, $query) or die("<p>".odbc_errormsg());
    echo $query;
```

The First Line works the 2nd line reports this error.

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the single quotes arround the table name.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO [Users] (FullName, Password, LocationsID, Position, Mobile, Note, EngineerID, FirstName, LastName, Username) VALUES ('".$FullName."','".$Password."','".$Location."','".$Position."','".$Mobile."','".$Note."','".$Engineer."','".$FirstName."','".$LastName."','".$Username."','".$Email."');";
```

Single quotes are for escaping strings.